# How can I distinguish a boolean NsNumber from a real number?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting a value back from an Objective C library (it's Firebase, but that doesn't really matter) of type `id`. The documentation states that this value will be an NSNumber for both boolean and numeric results. I want to take a different action based on whether or not this result corresponds to a boolean.

I know this is possible because printing out the class of the result via `NSStringFromClass([value class]);` gives "__NSCFBoolean" for booleans, but I'm not really sure how to correctly structure the comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `objCType` method gives information about the type of the data contained in the
number object:

```
NSNumber *n = @(1.3);
NSLog(@"%s", [n objCType]); // "d" for double
NSNumber *b = @YES;
NSLog(@"%s", [b objCType]); // "c" for char
```

The possible values are documented in
["Type Encodings"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)
in the "Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide".

Since `BOOL` is defined as `unsigned char`, it is reported as such by this method.
This means that you cannot distinguish it from a `NSNumber` object containing any `char`.
But it is sufficient to check between "boolean" and "numeric":

```
if (strcmp([obj objCType], @encode(BOOL)) == 0) {
    // ...
} else if (strcmp([obj objCType], @encode(double)) == 0) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1. This is good information. But, I'd say that needing to use this in practice in the scenario the OP describes is a bad code smell. Ideally the library and the calling code are designed in such a way that the significance of the NSNumber result is clear without resorting to runtime checks.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen: I do not disagree. I have seen this for example in FMDB, an Objective-C wrapper around SQLite (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/FMDatabase.m), where it is used to select the proper `sqlite3_bind_XXX()`, depending on the value that was passed as an object. But you are right, it is error-prone.